# how to set initial centers of K-means openCV c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, k-means, centroid

I am trying to do a segmentation  of an image  using OpenCv and Kmeans, the code that I  have just implemented is the following:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat src, Imagen2, Imagris, labels, centers,imgfondo;
    src = imread("C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ClusteringImage/data/leon.jpg");
    imgfondo = imread("C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ClusteringImage/data/goku640.jpg");
    if (src.empty()|| imgfondo.empty())
    {
        printf("Error al cargar imagenes");
        waitKey();
        return -1;
    }
    Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);
    for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                samples.at<float>(y + x*src.rows, z) = src.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[z];
    //KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS
    kmeans(samples, 2, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 1.0), 3, KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, centers);
    Mat new_image(src.size(), src.type());
    int cluster;
    if (centers.at<float>(0, 1) > centers.at<float>(1, 1))  cluster = 0;
    else        cluster = 1;
    for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
        {
            int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(y + x*src.rows, 0);
            if (cluster_idx == cluster)
            {
                new_image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0] = imgfondo.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0];
                new_image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1] = imgfondo.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
                new_image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2] = imgfondo.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2];
            }
            else
            {
                new_image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0] = src.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0];
                new_image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1] = src.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
                new_image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2] = src.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2];
            }
        }
    imshow("Original image", src);
    imshow("clustered image", new_image);
    waitKey();
}
```

It works pretty well and it does what i want, but i would like to  set my own initial centers values. I have read that it could be done using the flag "KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS" but im not very sure about how to use it, and how and where should I set the initial values.
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function allows you to directly set the initial *labeling*, not *centers*. Fortunately, since [k-means alternates between assignment and update steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Algorithms), you can get the effect you want indirectly.

---

From [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html):

> **labels** – Input/output integer array that stores the cluster indices for every sample.
>
> **KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS** During the first (and possibly the only) attempt, use the user-supplied labels instead of computing them from the initial centers. For the second and further attempts, use the random or semi-random centers. Use one of KMEANS_*_CENTERS flag to specify the exact method.

So, what the docs say is that you can set the initial *labeling*. If you want to do this, in your code

```
kmeans(samples, 2, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 1.0), 3, KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, centers);
```

initialize the 3rd parameter to be the input labels (for use in the first iteration).

---

If you want to get the effect of setting the initial centers, you can do the following:

1. Decide what the centers are.
2. Calculate the labeling like the algorithm does in [the assignment step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Algorithms).
3. Pass the resulting labeling to the function.

Comment: Now that you've set `attempts = 3; flags = KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS`, which algorithm will be used for the next 2 attempts? How to make sure that after the first attempt `KMEANS_PP_CENTERS` is used? Thanks