# How to calculate labels given centers of k-means?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, k-means

I read this question about how to set initial centers of k-mean on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803033/how-to-set-initial-centers-of-k-means-opencv-c). I read the answer, but I have no idea how to implement it in C++.

Could anyone give me any suggestions? I'd like to calculate first labels using centers that I already have and pass them to `kmeans` function with flag `KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS` for calculating new centers on new (but similar) data. Data in this case are features of images.

Comment: Just put them in your output vector.